# running the gstreamer pipeline (not able to get video and audio data in the callback)

Tags: gstreamer

I'm a newbie to gstreamer and I wanted to get the audio and video both buffers from a 3gp file and do some processing in the callback.

(I'm starting my pipeline into a separate thread, pipeline gives audio buffers in a callback AudioCallback and video buffers in VideoCallback.)

This is how my pipeline looks:

```
GstElement* audioQueue;//global variable , needed in on_pad_added (cant pass both while connecting demuxer to callback)
GstElement* videoQueue;//global variable , needed in on_pad_added (cant pass both while connecting demuxer to callback)


//static functions
static gboolean
bus_call (GstBus* bus, GstMessage* msg, gpointer    data)
{
  GMainLoop* loop = (GMainLoop*) data;

  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg))
  {
  case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;

  case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
      gchar  *debug;
      GError *error;

      gst_message_parse_error (msg, &error, &debug);
      g_free (debug);

      g_printerr ("Error: %s\n", error->message);
      g_error_free (error);

      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;
    }
  default:
      break;
  }
  return true;
}

static void link_two_elements(GstElement* src_element, GstElement* sink_element)
{
  if(!gst_element_link(src_element, sink_element))
      g_printerr ("Linking Error");

}

static void
 on_pad_added (GstElement *element,
              GstPad     *pad,
              gpointer    data)
{
  GstCaps *caps;
  GstStructure *str;
  gchar *tex;
  GstPad* sinkpad;

  /* check media type */
  caps = gst_pad_get_caps (pad);
  str = gst_caps_get_structure (caps, 0);
  tex = (gchar*)gst_structure_get_name(str);

  if(g_strrstr(tex,"audio"))
  {
    //GstElement *audioQueue = (GstElement *) data;
    sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad (audioQueue, "sink");

    if(sinkpad)
    {
        GstPadLinkReturn linkReturn = gst_pad_link (pad, sinkpad);
        gst_object_unref (sinkpad);
    }
  }

  if(g_strrstr(tex,"video"))
  {
    //GstElement *videoQueue = (GstElement *) data;
    sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad (videoQueue, "sink");

    GstPadLinkReturn linkReturn = gst_pad_link (pad, sinkpad);
    gst_object_unref (sinkpad);
  }
}

void runPipeline()
    {
    GMainLoop *loop;
    GstElement *__pPipeline, *source, *demuxer, *audioDecoder, *audioConverter, *audioresample, /**audioQueue,*/ *audioSink, *videoDecoder, *videoSink, /**videoQueue,*/ *ffmpegcolorspace, *videoscale;
    GstBus* bus;

     //Initialisation
    gst_init (null,null);

    loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

    // Create gstreamer elements
    __pPipeline = gst_pipeline_new("test_appsink");
    source = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "file-source");
    demuxer = gst_element_factory_make("qtdemux", "demuxer");
    //audioDecoder = gst_element_factory_make("ffdec_mp3", "audioDecoder");
    audioDecoder = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "audioDecoder");
    audioConverter = gst_element_factory_make("audioconvert", "audioConverter");
    audioresample = gst_element_factory_make("audioresample", "audioresample");
    audioSink = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "audioSink");
    audioQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue2", "audioQueue");
    //videoDecoder = gst_element_factory_make("ffdec_h264", "videoDecoder");
    videoQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue2", "videoQueue");
    videoDecoder = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin ", "videoDecoder");
    ffmpegcolorspace = gst_element_factory_make("ffmpegcolorspace", "ffmpegcolorspace");
    videoscale = gst_element_factory_make("videoscale", "videoscale");
    videoSink = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "videoSink");
    //appsink = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "sink-buffer");

    if (!__pPipeline || !source  || !demuxer || !audioDecoder || !audioConverter ||!audioresample || !audioSink || !videoSink || !audioQueue || !videoQueue || !videoDecoder || !ffmpegcolorspace || !videoscale )
    {
      //return -1;
    }

    //we set the input filename to the source element
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "location", "/etc/20000101-161404.3gp", NULL);

    //Make appsink emit the "new-preroll" and "new-buffer" signals.
    gst_app_sink_set_emit_signals ((GstAppSink*) audioSink, TRUE);
    gst_app_sink_set_emit_signals ((GstAppSink*) videoSink, TRUE);

    //we add a message handler
    bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (__pPipeline));
    gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
    gst_object_unref (bus);

     //we add all elements into the pipeline
    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (__pPipeline),
                    source, demuxer, videoDecoder, audioDecoder, audioConverter, audioresample, audioSink, videoSink,
                    audioQueue, videoQueue, ffmpegcolorspace, videoscale, NULL);


    //link source and demuxer seperately
    link_two_elements(source, demuxer);

    //link rest of the elements
    int retValVideoLinking = (int)gst_element_link_many (videoQueue, videoDecoder, ffmpegcolorspace, videoscale, videoSink, NULL);
    int retValAudioLinking = (int)gst_element_link_many (audioQueue, audioDecoder, audioConverter, audioresample, audioSink, NULL);

    gulong sigConRet =  g_signal_connect (demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), null);

    _ArAudioIn audioInstance = _ArAudioIn::GetArAudioInstance();

    g_signal_connect (videoSink, "new-buffer",  G_CALLBACK (AudioCallback), null);//AudioCallback static API
    g_signal_connect (audioSink, "new-buffer",  G_CALLBACK (VideoCallback), null);//VideoCallback static API

     //Set the pipeline to "playing" state
    GstStateChangeReturn state = gst_element_set_state (__pPipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    g_main_loop_run (loop);
    return null;
    }


I'm just getting a single video buffer in my Videocallback and also in the on_pad_addded : I'm getting a linking err for audio pad linking.
GST_PAD_LINK_NOFORMAT         = -4,

I'm trying to link the queue's sink pad to the pad recieved in on_pad_added, same is working for video but not for audio.

If anybody has any idea about this then please give me some pointers to get rid off this err and make this pipeline work.
```

Comment: It would be nice if you cleanup you code before asking us to debug it. As a general advice, check the return values and either log a warning or simply exit(1) to ensure that your pipeline setup works. I'd also start using a normal video and audiosink to check that it plays.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you cleanup you code before asking us to debug it. As a general advice, check the return values and either log a warning or simply exit(1) to ensure that your pipeline setup works (E.g. in the pad_added handler). I'd also start using a normal video and audiosink to check that it plays.

Finally, it is usually a bad idea to pull out data from the pipleine. Perhaps you could tell what you want to do with the data once you have it in your callback, so that we can give better advice.